# Shake update of index files after changes

Tags: shake-build-system

I use the `shake` build system and `watch` to keep files for a web site current. I cannot understand how to assure that an index file for a directory is changed when a file in the directory changes.

The index file for a directory lists all the files in it with their title and includes a link. From this, a HTML file is eventually produced by the shake process.
It requires reconstruction when one of the indexed files in the directory changes.

For each index file, the set of files indexed are marked as `needed` but this does not force the index file to be reconstructed when a file in the directory changes. I had expected that this would trigger the reconstruction of the index file if any of the needed files changes. This seems not to be a correct understanding.

What is the most effective method, to force a re-shake of the index file when a file in the directory changes. Is it sufficient to `touch` the index file to trigger the reconstruction? Or is it better to recompute the conversion of the `index.md` file to the next step (pandoc) and the following processing steps are then triggered by the shake logic? Or anything else?